# Will the "Zombie Siege" event happen on a Mushroom Island?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If someone builds a large village on a Mushroom Island,will the Zombie Siege still be a threat for the village? I know that on Mushroom Islands hostile mobs do not spawn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Minecraft Wiki:

> Sieges can occur in player-made villages and mushroom biomes, despite zombies not spawning in mushroom biomes naturally.

Comment: So, I must fortify the village even on the Mushroom Island.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a zombie siege if they swim to the island, but the probability of a large siege occurring is very low

Comment: Know that if just a stray zombie attacks a village is not a siege. 20 zombies attacking a village is a siege.

Comment: unlikely event in probability